# @font-face support in major email clients?

Tags: email, font-face, clients

Do major web and desktop email clients support the font-face feature? It would be only logical to assume that they don't but thought I'd ask anyway. Has anybody tested?

Comment: These answers are out of date now FYI.  Supported now by  iOS Mail, Mail.app on OS X, Lotus Notes 8, default Mail on Android, Outlook 2000, and Thunderbird. Check out http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email

Comment: There is an interesting claim among the comments of that post (link above); Gmail supports '@font-face through '@import in case the font is hosted on the same server as the one sending the email. Lovely world of email.

Answer (score 3):

## font-face email support

Campaign monitor and type-kit have done some research on this topic and have found support to be very rare. Only iPhone and Apple Mail work at all.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3044/does-font-face-work-in-email/

This is unfortunate as, as of January 2010 all of the major browsers support font-face.

- Safari 3.1
- IE - all versions
- Firefox 3.6
- Chrome 4
- Opera 10

See http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support

[image]

Comment: The OP was not asking about browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the font-face feature. It's most likely that it won't work on enough clients to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Since my curiosity was so big, I went, and ran a test with 17 different email clients (amen Litmus App) and as you might have guessed - pretty much none of them support @font-face. Of all the 17 clients only Apple Mail 3 and Apple Mail 4 actually supported it (amen Mac) and AOL Mail took so much time testing, I didn't even bother waiting for it, ditch minority.

So the conclusion is - unless the year number in you calendar shows 2020, don't bother using @font-face in your email newsletters, stick to Impact, and Georgia.