# non-webfonts in email

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any support for putting non-webfonts into emails now? Not just using @font-face, maybe another method?

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874718/font-face-support-in-major-email-clients) from some time back, along with some other questions and articles from about the same time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not consistently. There are popular email clients that still remove all CSS from HTML emails.

I was able to find a blog post on Campaign Monitor's site that has some test results from using this technique. Almost all email clients stripped out @font-face specifically, regardless of their general CSS support: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3044/does-font-face-work-in-email/.

Your best bet would be to use images, which isn't a great solution for a number of reasons, the main one being that images are commonly blocked by default and you want clients to be able to view the content of the email regardless.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Web-based email systems will simply strip out your font statements. MS Outlook uses the MS-Word engine to display mails and is incapable of doing this.

As far at HTML email goes, it's still 1999 and will remain that way for a loooooong time.